# Sentry Symfony How to capture user

Tags: php, symfony, sentry

I'm using sentry on my symfony project and I want to identify the Users who have the error. So I checked the sentry documentation I found out that -> https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/symfony/enriching-events/identify-user/

```php
\Sentry\configureScope(function (\Sentry\State\Scope $scope): void {
  $scope->setUser(['email' => 'jane.doe@example.com']);
});
```

But I don't where to put this function, and the documentation doesn't give information about that.
I tried to put in my index.php file and it's works but I don't how I can get the information of the current user.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably do this in your controller action that handles authentication. Or wherever you re-direct the User after successful login.
If the controller extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController` as it should, then it will have a `getUser` method that will return `UserInterface|object|null`

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
  /**
   * @Route("/user/profile", name="user_profile")
   */
  public function profile()
  {
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if($user){
      
      \Sentry\configureScope(function (\Sentry\State\Scope $scope): void {
        $scope->setUser(['username' => $user->getUsername()]);
      });

    }

    return $this->render('user/profile.html.twig', []);
  }
}
```